# Angular formats dates in en_US locale

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, localization

I'm trying to display dates in an Angular site. I use:

`{{ item.date | date:'short'}}` but I keep getting the dates as formatted in the en_US locale (Month/Day/Year Hour:Minute AM/PM) . I checked my browser's locale using [My Brwoser Info](http://mybrowserinfo.com/detail.asp?bhcp=1), and it is most certainly not a US locale - it is set to Israel as it should be.

By the way, item.date (before the filter) contains the date as follows: 2015-09-06T12:15:27.673Z.

Comment: From angular docs: 'short': equivalent to 'M/d/yy h:mm a'. You are getting the same format, so what do you want to get? What format you are expecting?

Comment: could write a `decorator` for date filter or define format yourself instead of `short`. Have you read the docs?

Comment: Also read the [i18n docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n) as referenced in the date docs

Comment: @ArtyomPranovich, the docs also add "for en_US locale", I'm not in the en_US locale, and the docs state that the "angular datetime filter uses the time zone settings of the browser".

Comment: @charlietfl, I don't want to define my own format, I want the format to depend on the user's browser.

Comment: I see that Angular has [locale info for he-IL and ar-IL](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngLocale). Are either one of those locale codes the ones you are expecting to see? What actual locale code are you getting from that browser info site?

Comment: As a follow up to my other Q: did you include the locale files of the codes you are expecting? Without that everything would default to en_US.